# Using value of a string at the left side of an if statement

Tags: c#

I'd like to use the value of a string at the left side of an if statement.
But I wasn't able to figure out how since an if statement looks inside the string and doesn't pass the value.

```
      private void ButtonConf()
      {
           int horizotal = 40;
           int vertical = 40;
           Label[] labelArray = new Label[9];

           for (int i = 0; i < labelArray.Length; i++)
        {
             string namestring = String.Format("label_" +
                                 i);
             string buttonstring = String.Format("this.",
                                 namestring);
             string id = i.ToString();

              labelArray[i] = new Label();

              labelArray[i].Size = new Size(40, 40);
              //labelArray[i].Click += (sender, e) => LabelClick(sender, e, i);


              labelArray[i].Location = new Point(horizotal, vertical);
            if ((i == 2) || (i == 5) || (i == 9))     
                {
                 vertical = 40;
                 horizotal = horizotal + 40;
                 }
             else
                vertical = vertical + 40;
                this.Controls.Add(labelArray[i]);
                labelArray[i].Name = namestring;
                labelArray[i].Text = "x";
                labelArray[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                labelArray[i].Font = new Font("Arial Black", 60);
                labelArray[i].Click += new EventHandler(delegate
                {
                    int click1 = 1;
                    string stringo = "click" + id.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(stringo);
                    if (stringo == 1) { MessageBox.Show("true"); } // Here's where the issue arrises
                });
             }
        }
```

EDIT: Hardcoded and added ==

Comment: You need to use `==`, and it will never be equal to 1

Comment: Fixed. Values were to be declared later

Comment: Ok, so you fixed `==`. Now what is the problem? What do you expect to happen vs. what actually happens?

Comment: I want the value of stringo to be passed to the valuename/left side of an if statement. So that I don't have to do this for every button myself. Code isn't complete yet. I'll go further once this is fixed.

Comment: What you're asking isn't clear, particularly, your focus on "_the left side of an if statement_". (And valuename doesn't make much sense either). Just to clarify, `if(myvar == 1)` is **IDENTICAL** to `if(1 == myvar)`.

Comment: I want the string value of stringo to be the variable's name inside the if statement.

Comment: Still don't understand, but try this: You wrote you want do avoid "having to do _this_ for every button". Can you show what it would be like if you DID do _this_ for every button? (So that "_this_" becomes clear, and the issue you're trying to solve will be obvious)

Comment: 1) An `if` statement **has NO “left” side**. 2) You cannot *directly* compare a `string` to an `int` for equality.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the code, I understand you want to count the number of times the label was clicked. Is that right?

If so, I would use a `Dictionary` to map the `label` id to a clicks counter

```
Label[] labelArray = new Label[9];
Dictionary<int, int> label_click_counter = new Dictionary<int, int>(9);
...
    this.Controls.Add(labelArray[i]);
    label_click_counter[i] = 0;
    labelArray[i].Name = namestring;
    labelArray[i].Text = "x";
    labelArray[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    labelArray[i].Font = new Font("Arial Black", 60);
    labelArray[i].Click += new EventHandler(delegate
    {
        label_click_counter[i] += 1;
        if (label_click_counter[i] == 1) { MessageBox.Show("true"); }
    });
```

Comment: Nay, I need the ID of the label and use the ID for variables in the clickevent.

Comment: Well, how many variables are there and what data are they storing?